# How to send POST Request and receive GET response

Tags: c++, sockets, http, post, get

I'm trying to send a POST Request and receive a GET response in return.

Here is my code :

```
#define IP "87.98.245.77"
#define Port 80

void getGETMessage(SOCKET s)
{
char *data = new char[2000];

recv(s, data, strlen(data), NULL);

int x = 3;
}

void SendPOSTMessage(SOCKET s)
{
string data = "POST /index.php?p=convert HTTP/1.1"
            "Host: convert2mp3.netConnection: keep-alive"
            "Content-Length: 80";
            "Cache-Control: max-age=0"
            "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
            "Origin: http://convert2mp3.net"
            "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36"
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            "Referer: http://convert2mp3.net/index.php?p=home"
            "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch"
            "Accept-Language: he-IL,he;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,de;q=0.2,fr;q=0.2";

if (send(s, data.c_str(), data.length(), NULL) < data.length())
{
    cout << "Error : " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    return ;
}

getGETMessage(s);
}

int main()
{
char *data = new char[200];

 WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

SOCKET ConnectSocket;
ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

sockaddr_in clientService;
clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP); // IP
clientService.sin_port = htons(Port); // Port

iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR *)& clientService, sizeof(clientService));

if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    cout << "Error" << endl;
    return 0;
}

SendPOSTMessage(ConnectSocket);

cin.get();
cin.get();
}
```

For some reason, I'm not getting anything back...
I tried getting the IP of this website :
`http://convert2mp3.net/index.php?p=home` and using cmd, it told me it's `http://87.98.245.77/` but it doesn't load in my browser... Maybe this is my error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your data is invalid. Each HTTP header needs to be terminated by \r\n, and you need another one after the last line of headers. And you're sending a Content-length of 80 but no content.

Further notes:

1. If send() returns a positive integer, calling WSAGetLastError() is meaningless. There has been no error, so what you will get is undefined. You should check for -1. In practice send() won't return a short count unless you're in non-blocking mode.
2. NULL is not a correct fourth parameter for send() or recv(), but 0 is.
3. There is no such thing as a 'GET response'. There are just HTTP responses.

Answer (score 0):

Problem (at least one) is in this part of code:

```
void getGETMessage(SOCKET s)
{
char *data = new char[2000];

recv(s, data, strlen(data), NULL);

int x = 3;
}
```

You didn't initialized data, so, there may be any symbols, so strlen(data) may return 0, if first symbol will be '\0', or something else, depends on when '\0' will appears.
Try to change strlen to sizeof.

Something like that:

```
void getGETMessage(SOCKET s)
{
char data[2000] = {0};

recv(s, data, sizeof(data)-1, NULL);
cout << data << endl;
int x = 3;
}
```

Comment: @ke4ktz marked you set message length, but don't send message body. Maybe there is a problem?

And I would join him to advice you to use some specified library, such as libcurl.

Comment: @Amit My answer explains why.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you're only sending the header information.  You specify a Content-Length of 80, but you're not sending any data.  Therefore, the server is still waiting on the data and is not sending a response back to you yet.

My suggestion would be to utilize some HTTP library rather than attempt to perform all the low-level functionality yourself.  Some suggestions are in this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798523/c-http-library).

Comment: I rather use the low level myself.

Then, how can I send the message? I mean, how do I write it? 
`Message:` or something ?

Comment: Your response is exactly the reason why you should use a HTTP library rather than do the low-level stuff yourself.  You need to have a very good understanding of the HTTP packet formatting in order to get it done properly.  Plus, there are situations in which you'll have to resend with different header information.

Comment: I've figured out my errors :
1) I forgot to add \r\n
2) I added a message inside too.

Now, I get a `404 page not found` error...
I dont know why.. This is the site :
`http://convert2mp3.net/index.php?p=home`
and it's ip is :`http://87.98.245.77/index.php`
So what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Well, it looks like your question was answered: You were only sending the headers and not the data.  Now you need to work on the format of your headers.  Your POST header is incorrect.  The query parameters don't go there...only the URL.

Comment: I've changed my Post data, and sended data too, but looks like the place im sending to is not good. If I have the domain, and I have it's IP, why do I get 404 when I try to enter from GOogle Chrome / using SOCKETS ?

Comment: @Amit Now you're understanding why I highly suggest that you use a HTTP library rather than trying to do it yourself.  I understand that you want to do it yourself, but I don't think you are aware of the complexity of what you're trying to do.  Use a library now to get it working.  Then, once you get proficient in the HTTP protocol, then you can attempt to do it all yourself.

Comment: If I'll use a HTTP library, will I have to include special files in my EXE or something? I want to be independed...

Comment: Yes, that's the way libraries work.  See the link I provided which includes links to various HTTP libraries.  Pick one that fits your needs.  Using libraries allows you to use well-tested code into your application.  Many applications make use of third-party libraries.